# Using django rest framework to send an image

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to use DRF to send an image to response to a certain url, for this purpose I have written these codes:

```
#Renderer class
class ImageRenderer(renderers.BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'image/png'
    format = 'image'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return data  

#view class
class ShowImage(APIView):    
    renderer_classes = (ImageRenderer,)    
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        print ('format', format)
        if format == 'image':
            image_file = open('path_to_image', 'rb')
            response = HttpResponse(image_file, content_type='image/png')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format('image_filename')

#urls.py
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
    url(r'image/?$', views.ShowImage.as_view())
])
```

But my problem is that always the input `format` is `None` although the `request.accepted_media_type` shows me `image/png`

I tried these requests using `httpie`:

```
http -vj 127.0.0.1:8000/api/image Accept:image/png
http -vj 127.0.0.1:8000/api/image.image Accept:image/png
```

But I could not get the format I expected. What is my mistake in using DRF?